# What is the conditional probability $P(Y|X=x)$, where $Y$ is binomial with Poisson distributed $n=X$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Question

> The number of patients visiting the dentist on a day follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda= 20$. Patients can either have one or two issues, the probability of a patient having one issue is $0.7$, and two issues is $0.3$.
>
> What is the expected total number of issues across all patients for a day?

I can figure this question out just using logic, the expected number of patients would be $20$ since the expected value of a Poisson variable is $\lambda$. And then $30\%$ will have two issues and $70\%$ will have one which equals $26$ total issues.

I am just not sure how to derive mathematically $P(Y|X=x)$ since we have to include that in our answer. I thought of treating the number of issues as binomial and then taking the total issues as $2np + nq$ and then using $E(Y) = E[E(Y|X)]$ but I am not sure that is along the lines of what the teacher asked, to derive the term $P(Y|X=x)$.

Comment: Welcome. Community here prefers typing Mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109). Since you are new contributor, the typing has been done. (If you can't see updated text, assume that typing process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ represent the random number of patients visiting the dentist in a day, and let $Y$ represent the number of issues that are seen by the dentist in a day.  We are given that $$X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 20).$$ But what is $Y$?  To understand the relationship between $Y$ and $X$, we introduce a third variable, say $B$, that counts the random number of patients that visit the dentist in a day who also have two issues.  Then $$B \mid X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = X, p = 0.3).$$  This is because for each patient that visits, their probability of having two issues is $0.3$, independent of any other patient.  So the total number of such patients, given that $X$ visited, is binomially distributed.

Therefore, $$Y \mid X = (X + B \mid X).$$  For instance, if $X = 18$, then $Y = 18 + B$ where $B$ is binomial with $n = 18$ and $p = 0.3$.  This is because we count all the patients who visited for having at least one issue, then count a second time the patients who had two issues.

From this, we calculate

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y] 
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X + B \mid X]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X + X p] \\
&= (1+p)\operatorname{E}[X] \\
&= (1+p)\lambda \\
&= (1.3)(20) \\
&= 26.
\end{align}$$

Notice how the fact that $\operatorname{E}[Y] = (1+p)\operatorname{E}[X]$ does not depend on $X$ being Poisson distributed, only that the conditional distribution $B \mid X$ is binomial, thus $\operatorname{E}[B \mid X] = Xp$.  While we can exploit the property of Poisson thinning to show that the *unconditional* distribution of $B$ is Poisson with rate $\lambda^* = \lambda p$, we do not need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,X_2$ denote the number of patients who visited throughout the course of a day with $1$ and $2$ issues, respectively.

Then $X_1\sim \text{Poisson}(20\times 0.7)$, $X_2=\text{Poisson}(20\times 0.3)$, and $X_1+2X_2$ denotes the total number of issues treated that day.

The expected number of issues is $$\mathbb{E}(X_1+2X_2)=14+2\times 6=26$$

Answer (score 0):

> What is the conditional probability $P(Y|X=x)$, where $Y$ is binomial with Poisson distributed $n=X$?

Clearly it is: $$\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)~=~\dbinom xy p^y(1-p)^{x-y}~\mathbf 1_{x,y\in\Bbb N~:~0\leq y\leq x}$$

In this case, $p=0.30$ the probability that a patient will have a second issue.  $Y$ being the count of patients with two issues.

$$\mathsf E(Y\mid X)~{=\sum_{y=0}^X\dbinom Xy p^y(1-p)^{X-y}\\=Xp}$$

So you may use this (a well known properties of a binomial distribution), and the Law of Total Expectation.

Thus the expected count of issues is :$\mathsf E(X+Y)~{=\mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\=\mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(Xp)\\=(1+p)~\lambda\\=(1.30)~ 20\\=26}$